# Marketing Cloud Field-Level-Encryption with SSJS not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, field-level-encryption

I want to use SSJS Script to insert a new Subscriber to the All Subscriber List in our Marketing Cloud, in which the field-level-encryption is turned on and the Email Address of the Subscriber should be showed as Email_Unavailable_XXXX@exct.net.
When the Subscriber automaticaly created from the first email sending or manuelle created from someone, the EmailAddress will be automaticaly encrypted. But when I add a new Subscriber via SSJS, as a result in All Subscriber List, the EmailAddress of this new Subscriber is not encrypted.

What is the Problem? How can I insert a Subscriber via SSJS and let the EmailAddress encrypted?